# Какая CMS подойдет для промо-сайтов?

Tags: wordpress, cms, joomla, modx, october

Всем привет.

Ищу CMS для небольших сайтов с не типовым дизайном, то-есть когда каждая страница уникальная, плюс есть типовые: каталог, новости. Пока что делаю все по старинке(без spa, pwa и другого сатанизма), но в будущем планирую попробовать, так что нормальное API у CMS будет плюсом.

В основном сейчас делаю на MODX Revo и в целом он +- устраивает, но из за проблем с поддержкой продукта, 3-ю версию ждут уже 7 лет, не хочется продолжать углублять в нее, писать модули и тд...

Из фишек modx, которые мне нужны в новой cms:

- Разные шаблоны для страниц
- TV поля - кастомные свойства(текст, изображения, ссылки на другую страницу и др.),
  которые крепятся к шаблону и задаются на странице
- Компоненты - меню, хлебные крошки, вывод списков(новости, товары и
  все в этом духе), форма обратной связи
- Хороший SEO

Отдельно выделю возможность получить любое свойство страницы по id, часто использую на главной сайта, например получить заголовок и ссылку страницы "О нас", после чего если контент-менеджер изменит ссылку или заголовок, на главное отобразится новая информация. 
В коде выглядит так `<a href="{13 | url}">{13 | resource : 'pagetitle'}</a>`, 13 - id страницы.
Выделил отдельно потому что нигде не встречал подобного и думаю не встречу.

Что уже посмотрел и что не понравилось:

- Битрикс - цена, нет параметров страницы, ужасная поддержка со стороны
  битрикса
- UMI cms - похоже мертвый проект, нет комьюнити, цена
- October cms - нет единой системы управления страницами, из коробки
  есть CMS Page - сделаны для разработчиков, на этих страницах нет
  WYSIWYG и переменных, а через менеджер-плагинов можно установить
  Static Page, у них есть WYSIWYG и переменные, как по мне получается небольшая каша.

Так же скажу что понравилось в October, редактирование страниц через IDE, плагин 'builder' через который можно легко создать новую сущность(блог, новости и т.д.)

Comment: October на базе laravel сделан, так что по идеи можно не беспокоиться о том что функционала не хватит или его нельзя будет расширить. Я на modx пишу, если проекты не сложные, если что то серьезное, то уже полноценный фреймворк юзаю (yii2, laravel, django)

Comment: Всё, что описано в вопросе, составляет очень малую часть функционала WordPress.

Comment: В Modx вы тоже можете из IDE разрабатывать, не обязательно хранить код чанков/сниппетов/шаблонов в бд и работать с ними из админ-панели

Comment: @Spartak Да я понимаю что october очень расширяемый, да и laravel мне нравится. Но из за изначального минимализма системы получается каша из плагинов и страниц. А чистый фреймворк не подходит потому что нужно простое добавление страниц и управление контент менеджером. А modx вас не напрягает из за постепенного увядания?

Comment: @Fapalz я бы не сказал что он увядает. Да, выпуск третей версии очень затянулся, ну и что с того?) CMS отлично подходит для реализации контентного сайта, сайта-визитки, даже не плоха для интернет-магазина. При более глубоком изучении можно и свои плагины писать(кстати намного проще чем на WP). Мне очень нравится что я всегда могу сниппет там написать и легко его вызвать напрямую или хуком из другого сниппета, передав в него необходимые параметры, если немного функционала не хватает. Очень удобное управление кэшированием.

Comment: Так же там очень гибко настраивается система прав доступа. Можно создать несколько групп пользователей и выдать им различные права для админки (Контент-менеджер, администратор и т.д) Можно нанимать штат менеджеров и давать им урезанные права, что бы они не видели программный код и секретные данные, не могли вносить правки в код и видеть/изменять системные настройки, но могли контентить.

Comment: @Spartak знаю, поддерживаю 3 сайта на modx, которые сам сделал.  В целом modx мне нравится, есть конечно косяки с внешним видом некоторых плагинов, но это обусловлено разнообразием extjs. И с кэшои у меня были проблемы при использовании fenom.